# T-SQL split string by space?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Nation column. How can split by space in T-SQL?

| Nation |
| --- |
| nl NED |
| eng ENG |
| ma MAR |
| ng NGA |

Desired Output:

| Nation |
| --- |
| NED |
| ENG |
| MAR |
| NGA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the consistency of your data:

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`...

```sql
DECLARE @String varchar(10) = 'nl NED';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX(' ', @String)+1, 10)
```

If you ONLY ever need the last 3 characters, then you could also use:

```sql
DECLARE @String varchar(10) = 'nl NED';
SELECT RIGHT(@String, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CHARINDEX` to find the space, and `STUFF` to remove the characters up to it:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(YourColumn,1,CHARINDEX(' ',YourColumn),'') AS NewString
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```